# Popup from iframe onload event is blocked

Tags: javascript, iframe, popupwindow, window.open, onload-event

I am trying to work around the poor quality of a website's shopping cart API, so I am creating the functionality by submitting a form to their site within an iframe using Javascript.

Basically, these are the steps that occur:

1. User clicks "checkout" button
2. Form is submitted targeting the iframe (this adds items to the user's cart on 3rd party site)
3. With the onload event of the iframe, window.open is used to bring up the 3rd party shopping cart page.

This is not interpreted as a direct user interaction creating the popup, so it gets blocked by popup blockers.

I may end up just displaying the shopping cart page within the iframe, but does anyone know a way to get the pop-up method to work?